Logger dependency injection error (Cannot read properties of undefined)
When I give the logger as a dependency to the class I am getting the following error:
Screenshot of error message details
E:\my_site\src\common\database\MongoDBConnector.ts:11
constructor(@inject(COMMON_TYPES.Logger) logger: ILogger) {
^TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Logger')
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\my_site\src\common\database\MongoDBConnector.ts:11:38)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
at Module.m._compile (E:\my_site\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (E:\my_site\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\my_site\src\common\common_injection_container.ts:4:1)

this is inversify.config.ts
import { Container, ContainerModule } from 'inversify';
import { commonContainer, COMMON_TYPES } from '../common_injection_container';
import { ILogger } from '../../common/interfaces/ILogger';

const appContainer = new Container();

appContainer.load(commonContainer);

const logger = appContainer.get<ILogger>(COMMON_TYPES.Logger);

interface ContainerDefinition {
    container: ContainerModule;
    name: string;
}

const containers: ContainerDefinition[] = [
];

containers.forEach(({ container, name }) => {
    try {
        appContainer.load(container);
        logger.info(`${name} container loaded successfully`);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Failed to load ${name} container`);
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            logger.trackError(error);
        } else {
            logger.error('An unknown error occurred while loading the container.');
        }
    }
});

export { appContainer };

this is common_injection_container.ts
import { ContainerModule, interfaces } from 'inversify';
import { ILogger } from './interfaces/ILogger';
import Logger from './utils/Logger';
import { MongoDBConnector } from './database/MongoDBConnector';


const COMMON_TYPES = {
    Logger: Symbol.for('Logger'), 
    MongoDBConnector: Symbol.for('MongoDBConnector'), 


};

const commonContainer = new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    bind<ILogger>(COMMON_TYPES.Logger).to(Logger).inSingletonScope();

    bind<MongoDBConnector>(COMMON_TYPES.MongoDBConnector).to(MongoDBConnector);


});

export { commonContainer, COMMON_TYPES };

this is MongoDBConnector.ts
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { ILogger } from '../../common/interfaces/ILogger';
import { COMMON_TYPES } from '../../common/common_injection_container';

@injectable()
export class MongoDBConnector {
    private logger: ILogger;

    constructor(@inject(COMMON_TYPES.Logger) logger: ILogger) {
        if (!logger) {
            throw new Error('Logger not found during MongoDBConnector injection');
        }
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async connectToMongoDB(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI!, {
                serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000, 
            });
            this.logger.info('Connected to MongoDB'); 
        } catch (error: any) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                this.logger.error('Could not connect to MongoDB'); 
                this.logger.error(`Error details: ${error.message}`); 
            } else {
                this.logger.error('Could not connect to MongoDB with an unknown error');
            }
            throw error; 
        }
    }
}


I think the problem might be that your class is being hoisted and this causes the class to be defined before COMMON_TYPE is imported (making it undefined). So, try changing the class definition to export const MongoDBConnector = class MongoDBConnector {... Then I think it might work just fine.

The problem might be because of the hoisting that happens when defining a class.
It looks to me that classes and functions declarations are hoisted first (ahead of everything else). This means that the import will be evaluated after the class is defined (although uninitialized).
For example, if your code is like this:
import { something } from 'path/to/file';
class type extends something {}

Then it will be evaluated like this:
class type extends something {} // something is a promised value
import { something } from 'path/to/file'; // changes something value

It is possible to change the order of the class definition by placing the class in a variable, like this:
export const MongoDBConnector = class MongoDBConnector {
  // ...
};

Maybe just changing this will work.

Classes are not hoisted, they are temporal-dead-zoned so that's not likely it either, unfortunately.  But it's worth a shot!

Thank you, my problem is completely solved! I defined the types in another file separately and as variables! Thank you
